# Every Partially ordered set has a maximal independent subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am working on this problem:-

> Every Partially ordered set has a maximal independent subset.

Definition:Let $\langle E,\prec\rangle$ be a partially ordered set. A subset  $A\subset E$ is called independent set if for any two of its elements $a , b$ neither $a\prec b$ or $ b\prec a$.

My attempt:- I am trying to apply the  Teichmüller–Tukey lemma,but from my thinking I see  Teichmüller–Tukey lemma only give guarantee having the maximal subset. 
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical application of Zorn's lemma, but you can just as well use the Teichmüller–Tukey lemma instead.

**HINT:** Show that $\mathcal F=\{A\subseteq E\mid A\text{ is independent}\}$ has finite character. What can you conclude about a maximal element in $\cal F$?

Comment: This is applying Tukey-Teichmüller Lemma, since if we show that $\mathcal F$ has finite character then Teichmüller–Tukey lemma will give us maximal element for free and of course it will be independent.

Comment: Yes, of course this is an application of the Teichmüller–Tukey lemma.

Comment: My Proof of $\mathcal F$ that has finite character :  $\rightarrow$ Let $A$ be independent then any subset of it is also independent also. $\leftarrow$ Assume there is a set $A$ such that every finite subset of $A$ is independent. if possible $A$ is not independent hence there is two element at least in which are comparable, hence the set contains only these two element is not independent which is contradiction since its finite.  is this arrgument right?